# Programming at a customized address on STM32

Tags: c, stm32

Context : I'm trying to create my own bootloader on STM32L433CCT6 microcontroller. To do this, I have create a software to read the .hex and to send datas to the microcontroller via the USB of my PC. This part is OK. The reception of datas is done through a USB connecteur on the mricrocontroller board and is OK too. And I write to the right address (adress start : 0x0800A000).

Now, the issue : To check if the program write well, I have coded a program that blinks a LED. To start, I make sure the program works by programming it with an STLink. When I program it at the adress 0x08000000, the program works. But when i program it at 0x0800A000, it doesn't work.
To change the start adress, I have changed :

- the FLASH ORIGINE in the file .ld from 0x08000000 to 0x0800A000
- VECT_TAB_OFFSET in system_stm32L4xx.c from 0x00000000 to 0x0000A000
- I make sure the memory is blank before programming

The question is how programing at a customized address ? (with a STLink to start).
Is there any other constant to modify ?

So, if you have an idea to solve it, I would be interested.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you have set up your boot pins so that MCU boots from Flash memory, then start address will be 0x0800000 or 0x00000000. You need to put your bootloader at one of these addresses. After this, the application can be linked in (.ln) somewhere else in flash and bootloader can jump to application address after it has been flashed. As you write, you also need to change the VECT_TAB_OFFSET for the application.

Comment: You need either a bootloader located at adress 0x0800 0000 that installs the new software and jumps to it. or to modifiy the boot adress of the product, I don't remember is it's possible on the STM32L4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.